# How can I generate minified file only for Production with Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, sass

I would like to generate a minified CSS file only for the Production with Webpack. The present webpack configuration works and it converts SCSS to CSS with minified code.

But I don't need minified CSS during the Development. I need it only in Production. I spent a lot of time on Webpack and it's my 5th day messing around with it. So, the following is the structure I am looking for:

```
assets/
-/css/
  --index.css (Non Minified for Development with Source Map)
  --index.min.css (Minified for Production)
```

My present Webpack Config is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const RemovePlugin = require('remove-files-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    index: "./assets/scss/index.scss",
  }, 
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets')
  },
  
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "css/[name].css",
    }),
    new RemovePlugin({
      after: {
        include: ["./assets/js/style.min.js"]
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,"css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

Highly appreciate it if anyone could help me with it with simple explanations as Webpack generally seems to be complicated. Briefly, I need an "index.css" without minified in Development and an "index.min.css" minified version generated only for Production.

Hopes someone can help me. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try changing `mode: 'production'` to `mode: 'development'` to check if it's still minimized.

Comment: @yousoumar i tried it already and not seeing any changes in files

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the config?

Comment: @yousoumar :) it works in "development" mode after restart npm command, not server. Because I am looking for this solution for PHP projects where I just need unminifed CSS version for development and minified version for Production. Hopes i am almost near of the solution because I just need webpack to convert it with ".min" string along with the original file name. Thank You for your assistance!

Comment: I see! Check my below answer and let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack by default compresses files when you are compiling for production, basically when the `mode` key is set to `production` (which is the default value if you didn't set any).

A common way is to pass a `NODE_ENV=production` to the npm script for the production, and nothing for development mode, as an example, like so:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "...",
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack"
},
```

And if you are on a computer with Windows OS on it:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "...",
  "build": "SET NODE_ENV=production&webpack"
},
```

And use it in `webpack.config.js` to adapt the `mode` key value and hence the outputted files, something like:

```js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const RemovePlugin = require("remove-files-webpack-plugin");

//
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "production" : "development"; 

module.exports = {
  //
  mode: mode,
  entry: {
    index: "./assets/scss/index.scss",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets"),
  },

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      //
      filename: mode === "production" ? "css/[name].min.css" : "css/[name].css", 
    }),
    new RemovePlugin({
      after: {
        include: ["./assets/js/style.min.js"],
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! When i run "npm run build" i am getting following alert:
'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. What will be the issue

Comment: Are you using a computer with a Window OS on it? If so, try changing the command from `"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack"` to `"build": "SET NODE_ENV=production&webpack"`

Comment: Excellent!!! It works...This is the Power of Real Developer. Thank You Very Much. I use the following script for differentiate Dev and Prod. Let me know is it Good Practice. 
  "build": "SET NODE_ENV=production&webpack",
  "dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development&webpack"
Also  can I enable Source map for SCSS, so that I can track the line number of SCSS from browser inspect.

Comment: Glad I could help @shaijuelayidath! Yeah, you could do that if you want to set NODE_ENV=development explicitly. Have a good one :)